# Symfony 2.7.3 cookie issue

Tags: php, symfony, cookies

I am quite new to Symfony, and I want to set up a website were an user can select different board to display. All the board are in my twig template and are hidden if the value of the cookie is 0. If the user click on the menu, the value of the cookie will change to 1, displaying the board.
However, when I click on the menu, the first time, it does not change anything, but the second time, it work perfectly.

This is how I set up my cookie:

```
$var = 0;
    $response = new Response();
    $response->headers->setCookie(new Cookie('stream', $var, time() + 3600));
    $response->send();
```

And this is how I change the value of the cookie:

```
    $response = new Response();
    $cookie = $this->getRequest()->cookies->get('stream');
    $var = 1;
    $response->headers->setCookie(new Cookie('stream', $var, time() + 3600));
    return $response;
```

Edit: Here is my controller

```
 public function streamAction()
{

    $advert = $this->getAdvertEntity();
    $stream = $this->getStreamEntity();

    $cookie = $this->getRequest()->cookies->get('stream');
    if (!isset($cookie) || $cookie == 0) {
        $var = 1;
        $response->headers->setCookie(new Cookie('stream', $var, time() + 3600));
        $response->sendHeaders();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('stream', array(
            "adverts" => $advert,
            "liststream" => $stream
        ));
    }
    $content = $this->get('templating')->render('IVPlatformBundle:Advert:Advert.html.twig', array(
        "adverts" => $advert,
        "liststream" => $stream
    ));
    return new Response($content);
}
```

I really don't know what is wrong, so any help will be nice :)

Thanks

Comment: Seems you are setting it right. Maybe you are confused about how to read it? Also remember the cookies value is only sent with the next browser request, so the new value can only be read from the request then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you first time visit the route, cookie is not set in request, you receive it in response. Solution is to make redirect to the same route if cookie changed:

```
$cookie = $this->getRequest()->cookies->get('stream');
    if (!isset($cookie) || $cookie == 0) {
        $var = 1;
        $response->headers->setCookie(new Cookie('stream', $var, time() + 3600));
        $response->sendHeaders();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('actual_route');
    }
    // Do other stuff if cookie set to 1.
    return $response;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it still does not work :(. I used your answer in my controller called when I click the button. But I have the same issue as before

Comment: It works for me. Maybe try to use 0 as string: `if(... $cookie = '0'`.

Comment: Still not working... But I use session instead of cookie, and it work perfectly :)